# Find time between dataframe date column and a reference date in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame `df` with a `'date of birth'` column the head of which the head looks which looks like:

```
            DoB
0    19/12/1973
1    22/05/1969
2    23/09/1959
3    04/08/1963
4    25/03/1962
```

I am trying to create a new column which has the number of years between this column and a reference date variable called refDate which is set to: `2017-03-31` and has a type of `<class 'datetime.date'>`.  I am looking for the folling new column in the df dataframe

```
Age
43
47
57
53
55
```

I have tried the follwing:

```
df['Age'] = df.loc[(refDate - ['Date of birth']).years]
```

but can't get a new column called `Age`. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line for `df['Age']` is not correct, Use the following to get the desired output, First substract `df['DoB']` from `refDate` then divide with [`timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion) for conversion of days to years as :

```
df['DoB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DoB'])
df['Age'] = (pd.to_datetime('2017-03-31') - df['DoB'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')

print(df)
         DoB        Age
0 1973-12-19  43.280834
1 1969-05-22  47.858614
2 1959-09-23  57.520688
3 1963-04-08  53.980575
4 1962-03-25  55.018241
```

Or If you want years in integers then:

```
df['Age'] = ((pd.to_datetime('2017-03-31') - df['DoB'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')).astype(int)
print(df)
         DoB  Age
0 1973-12-19   43
1 1969-05-22   47
2 1959-09-23   57
3 1963-04-08   53
4 1962-03-25   55
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `.loc`. With [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) you access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array.

Answer (score 0):

Use apply to get the date diff in years

```
df.DoB.apply(lambda x: (refDate - x).days // 365)
```

*Demo*

```
In [1]: df.DoB = pd.to_datetime(df.DoB)

In [2]: refDate = datetime(2017, 3, 31)

In [3]: df['age'] = df.DoB.apply(lambda  x: (refDate - x).days // 365)

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
         DoB  age
0 1973-12-19   43
1 1969-05-22   47
2 1959-09-23   57
3 1963-04-08   54
4 1962-03-25   55
```